# Calling Twilio API from R using RCurl

Tags: r, twilio, rcurl

I am trying to send SMS through Twilio using R. The following code works but after sending a SMS, it tries to keep the connection option.

```
library(RCurl)
Twilio_Account_SID <- "YourKey"
Twilio_Account_TOKEN <- "YourToken"
Number_From <- "+44*********"
Number_To <- "+44*********"
the_url <- paste("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/",
                 Twilio_Account_SID,"/Messages.XML",sep="")
output <- postForm(the_url,
                   .opts = list(
                     userpwd = paste(Twilio_Account_SID,":",Twilio_Account_TOKEN,sep=""),
                     useragent = "RCurl",
                     verbose = TRUE
                   ),
                   .params = c(From = Number_From, 
                               To = Number_To, 
                               Body = "I am sending a test message" 
                   )
)
```

Then I get this message:

```
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #1 to host api.twilio.com left intact
Error: UNAUTHORIZED
```

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: You authentication is failing. You didn't set the required content type as in the docs... https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request. "But be sure to set the HTTP Content-Type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for your requests if you are writing your own client."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fixed it accordingly. Still got the error but was able to fix it with `options(RCurlOptions = list(httpauth=AUTH_BASIC))`.